# Approximate unit/identity in Banach and or C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

In Banach algebras and C*-algebras, the concept of approximate unit (or approximate identity) is defined as nets, rather than sequences. My question is, since the underlying space is Banach and the convergence is norm-convergence, why do we need to use nets, rather than sequences?

Comment: The underlying space beinya banach space (or more generally first countable) allows us to reduce continuity and other topological properties to the case of sequences, but this has nothing to do, with the approximate unit" which has to do with the banach algebra structure (for example a commutative C*-Algebra has a "countable" approximate unit iff its spectrum is $\sigma$ compact, which isn't verified in general).

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Can you please comment whether my understanding is correct: even though the non-unital algebra is Banach or C*, it might be embeded in a larger unital algebra whose topology might not necessarily be first-countable? Only when that larger algebra is also first-countable, we can have sequences as approximate units? With my shallow understanding, this seems to me a possible scenario at least. Thanks

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Also, does the concept of $\sigma$-unital only apply to C*-algebras? Or does it also apply to general non-unital Banach algebras? If it can, is there any condition for a Banach algebra to be $\sigma$-unital?

Comment: Also, at least for $C*$-algebras, separability allows you to obtain an approximate unit that is a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Blackadar's
"Operator Algebras -
Theory of $C^*$-Algebras
and von Neumann
Algebras'':

II.4.2.4 Proposition. A $C^*$-algebra contains a strictly positive element if
and only if it has a countable approximate unit. (Such a $C^*$-algebra is called
$σ$-unital.)

A positive element $h$ in a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is said to be *strictly positive* iff $φ(h)>0$, for every state $φ$ on $A$.

Comment: Are there any results specifying when there exist sequential approximate units in general Banach algebras?

Comment: I think not.  This is perhaps because there aren't nice existence results for approximate units of any kind.  Perhaps the best thing one can say is that, if there is an approximate unit, and the algebra is separable, then there is a sequential approximate unit.